# Search columns for keywords from a list and return any matches to a different column

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thanks in advance for any assistance. I have a work sheet with two tabs named DATA PULL and LIST. The LIST tab contains a list of keywords (250 words) in column A. I need to search for those key words in columns P and Q on the DATA PULL tab and return any matches to column I(the data is in a table). Columns P and Q contain multiple words or sentences.

The code below does what I need but the list of key words is on the same sheet. This code also deletes letters from my table headers for some reason.

```
Sub GetWords()

Dim wrdLRow As Integer
Dim wrdLp As Integer
Dim CommentLrow As Integer
Dim CommentLp As Integer
Dim fndWord As Integer
Dim Sht As Worksheet

On Error Resume Next 'Suppress Errors... for when we don't find a match

'Define worksheet that has data on it....
Set Sht = Sheets("DATA PULL")

'Get last row for words based on column A
wrdLRow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

'Get last row for comments based on column C
CommentLrow = Sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

'Loop through lists and find matches....
For CommentLp = 2 To CommentLrow
    For wrdLp = 2 To wrdLRow
       'Look for word...
       fndWord = Application.WorksheetFunction.Search(Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A"), Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "P"))
       'If we found the word....then
       If fndWord > 0 Then
           Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
           fndWord = 0 'Reset Variable for next loop
       End If
    Next wrdLp
    Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = Mid(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I"), 3, Len(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I")) - 2)

Next CommentLp


End Sub
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

[LIST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjPz9.png)

[DATAPULL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQSdt.png)

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Get rid of the error suppression. You need to see what else goes wrong. 2. Use the VBA `Range.Find` method and test for non-finds there. 3.  Define the desired worksheet objects so you can search on one sheet and write to another sheet. 4. Use `Option Explicit` so as to avoid typos and other problems.

Comment: Ron, Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some tips for your code:
Using a

```
    On error Resume Next
```

like you are using is a bad practice and can result in trouble. You might have other errors that won't show up because of that, and this will prevent you from debugging them and finding the problem. I would recommend using it only before the problematic line, and after that using

```
    On Error goto 0
```

to resume showing and finding other possible errors.

A way of totally avoiding having to use "On Error Resume Next" is using the "Like" Operator. If you use

```
    If Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "P") Like "*" & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A") & "*" Then
        Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
    End If
```

You can do the same thing without worrying about errors. Basically, "Like" does a search to see if a text looks like the other. The two "*" means any kind and number of characters, so all together means that Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "P") must be like: any kind and number of characters, followed by the value of Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A"), followed by any kind or number of characters. Just like "Search" =) !

Doing this change also forced me to adapt the way you are dealing with the starting "; " in your code, but also for a better way:

```
    Dim wrdLRow As Integer
    Dim wrdLp As Integer
    Dim CommentLrow As Integer
    Dim CommentLp As Integer
    Dim fndWord As Integer
    Dim DataSht As Worksheet
    Dim ListSht as Worksheet

    'Define the worksheets
    Set DataSht = Sheets("DATA PULL")
    Set ListSht = Sheets("LIST")


    'Get last row for words based on column A
    wrdLRow = ListSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    'Get last row for comments based on column C
    CommentLrow = DataSht.Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    For CommentLp = 2 To CommentLrow
      For wrdLp = 2 To wrdLRow
        If LCASE(DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "P")) Like "*" & LCASE(ListSht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")) & "*" Then
          If DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") <> "" Then
            DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") & "; " & ListSht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
          Else
            DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = ListSht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
          End If
        ElseIf LCASE(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "Q")) Like "*" & LCASE(Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")) & "*" Then
          If NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") <> "" Then
            NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") = NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
          Else
            NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") = Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")
          End If
        End If
      Next wrdLp
    Next CommentLp
```

This code runs for me without a problem, but so did yours. I am assuming you didn't share your whole code, also because you mentioned two columns and only wrote the code for one. I think the problem might be in the part you didn't share, and perhaps this modification I wrote, without the "On Error Resume Next", you help you find it!

I just hoped I didn't get confused with the variables and list, but I think now you can have a good idea of what I am doing. Hope it helps.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for the reply and assistance. I should have clarified in my original post that I didn't write the code. I am not very knowledgeable about VBA, I have just been lucky in the past when finding and changing a few pieces of the code. That is the whole code that I have. There technically isn't a problem with the list being on the same sheet, I would just like the list out of view from the user. I was hoping the new code could search column P and Q so I wouldn't needed to run two different macros. I hope this helps.

Comment: I did notice that when I ran your code against the orginial, that the original found about 4000 matches and yours found about 400. not sure why that would have happened. just thought it might be good information. Again, thanks for your time.

Comment: About the difference, since you used "Search", it might be Capital letters. "Search" is not case sensitivity, but the vba command "Like" is. This is easy to avoid using LCASE(element) before each of the two elements, to convert them both to lower case.
I will edit the code to look for both columns and the lower case problem (in case that is it)

Comment: Ok this time it put words from my list (column A on the LIST Tab) on a new sheet that I had to create called NovoNome. The words were not matches from columns P and Q on the DATA PULL tab. Any words found (in P and Q columns) from the list (column A on the LIST Tab) should be copied to column I on the DATA PULL tab. Hope I am not confusing you with my explanation, I can only imagine how hard it is to interpret this stuff so thanks again for trying.

Comment: Don't worry, we will get there =). But right now I am a little confused. You said somehting about different sheets. Would you like everything in the same sheet, in column I? Or in a new sheet?

Comment: Daniel, I added some pics to help. There are 2 sheets DATAPULL and LIST. The word list is on the sheet named LIST. I need to search for those words in columns P and Q on the DATAPULL sheet and if the word is found, copy it to the same row in column I of the sheet DATAPULL.

Comment: Ok, now I think I see what you need. Check the code, see if it works, and more importantly, did you understand what we are doing and why?

Comment: it was stuck at this line: ElseIf LCASE(Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "Q")) Like "*" & LCASE(Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")) & "*" Then, I changed Sht.Cells(CommentLp, "Q" to DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "Q" and (Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")) to (ListSht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")). That debugs now past that point but I still get a run-time error '424' object required. When I try to debug it, it just loops.

Comment: I fixed it. This section needed to be adjusted:

 If NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") <> "" Then
            NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") = NewSht.Cells(writeRow, "A") & "; " & Sht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")

To this:

If DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") <> "" Then
            DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") = DataSht.Cells(CommentLp, "I") & "; " & ListSht.Cells(wrdLp, "A")

Comment: To answer your previous question about understanding what we are doing, not really, haha. I am trying to figure it out, I understand small parts after I see things like this work and obviously I figured something was different with your last edit. Trial and error seems to work alot.
Thanks a ton for all of your assistance.

Comment: Glad to see you understood enough to correct some mistakes I made. Hope it works now as it should. If you need any more assistance let me know, otherwise don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try this:

**EDITED VERSION:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim LRA As Long, i As Long, LRP As Long, LRQ As Long, LRI As Long
    Dim SearchingValue As String
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook

        Set ws1 = .Worksheets("DATA PULL")
        Set ws2 = .Worksheets("LIST")

        With ws1

            LRP = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
            LRQ = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row

            Set rng = .Range("P1:P" & LRP, "Q1:Q" & LRQ)

        End With

        With ws2

            LRA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            For i = 1 To LRA

                SearchingValue = .Range("A" & i).Value

                For Each cell In rng

                    If InStr(1, cell.Value, SearchingValue) > 0 Then
                        With ws1
                            LRI = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
                            .Range("I" & LRI + 1).Value = "Value " & """" & .Range("A" & i).Value & """" & " appears in sheet DATA PULL, " & "column " & cell.Column & ", row " & cell.Row & "."
                        Exit For
                        End With
                    End If

                Next cell

            Next i

        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Error, Thanks for your input. Your Code seems to work but I would need the results returned to column I on the Data Pull tab instead of a message box.

Comment: @Gaminggeek see **EDITED VERSION**

Comment: Error, I am getting a Compile error: End if without block if

Comment: @Gaminggeek my bad. Try again!

Comment: Ok, it runs but doesn't pull all the matches. I am sure this is due to my explanation. When the code runs, it should search for key words on the LIST tab (there are 250 words in column A on that tab). The data to be searched is in columns P and Q on the DATA PULL tab. I need a word found in P and Q to be placed in the same row in column I. your code returned this, Value "ARC" appears in sheet DATA PULL, column 16, row 1645., where all I would need is the word ARC. It found 16 matches but the other code I posted found over 4000. Thanks again, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Please upload a photo for both sheets and the desirable outcome

Comment: Error, I added some pics to help. There are 2 sheets DATAPULL and LIST. The word list is on the sheet named LIST. I need to search for those words in columns P and Q on the DATAPULL sheet and if the word is found, copy it to the same row in column I of the sheet DATAPULL.

Comment: Error. Daniel Fittipaldi provided code that worked. Thanks for all your time on trying to assist with this also.